# GoogleMaps Optimize waypoints and relate to original sequence

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using googlemaps api to route and optimize a set of waypoints from a Database.  The waypoints are fed in, in random order.  Once the waypoints are optimized via googlemaps to create a proper route order, I need a way to correlate them to the original sequence so I can update the route order in a database.

For example my original data from the DB might look like the below (LoadNum is blank to start):

```
    LoadNum Order address   City    State   Zip
   blank    1   456 Elm Street  Chicago IL  12345
    blank   2   123 Main Street Cleveland   OH  12345
    blank   3   678 Market Street   Beverly Hills   CA  90210
```

After GoogleMaps Optimizes the route the addresses could be changed a little to the nearest match on each of those streets, as in below with the ranges;

```
LoadNum Order address   City    State   Zip
       blank    2   120-160 Main Street Cleveland   OH  12345
       blank    1   200-300 Elm Street  Chicago IL  12345
       blank    3   678 Market Street   Beverly Hills   CA  90210
```

GoogleMaps also returns a route segment number that I want to assign as loadnumber in the database, but I don't have a way to guarantee the match.  If I could pass an identifier (OrderNumber) to googlemaps, and have it returned with that record that would be ideal, so even if the address has changed I know order number 'x' is stop 1.

Code snippets below, first is the JavaScript, near the bottom I'm capturing routeSegment and EndAddress into a variable (actually a text field for now so I can see it):

```
 directionsService.route({
            origin: document.getElementById('StartBoxAjax').value,
            destination: document.getElementById('EndBoxAjax').value,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];
                var string = [];
                document.getElementById('<%=JScriptParm.ClientID %>').value = ""
                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
                summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
                // For each route, display summary information.
                for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    var routeSegment = i + 1;
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                        '</b><br>';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                    //document.getElementById('JScriptParm').value += routeSegment;
                    document.getElementById('<%=JScriptParm.ClientID %>').value += routeSegment + ',' + route.legs[i].end_address + '|';
                   // string += routeSegment + ',' + route.legs[i].end_address + '|';
                   // document.getElementById('<%=JScriptParm.ClientID %>').value = string;

                }
```

Then in code behind I would like to do a DB update where "AddressInDB matches Address returned from JavaScript".

```
 protected void AssignLoadNum(string city, string state, string stop)
    {
        //Call Stored proc to update load number.
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnitureDB"].ConnectionString;
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = state;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = city;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stop", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(stop);


        cmd.CommandText = "UpdateLoadOrd";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //var dt = new DataTable();

    }
```

In my example the parameters are City and State, but that is not going to be specific enough.  The long and short of it is, is there a way to pass an identifying parameter through GoogleMaps Javascript API that will be returned/maintained, or is there another way to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DirectionsRoute object (`route` variable in your code) contains information that defines relationship between original waypoints and re-ordered waypoints. Have a look at the property `waypoint_order` in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRoute

> If **optimizeWaypoints** was set to **true**, this field will contain the re-ordered permutation of the input waypoints. For example, if the input was:
>
> Origin: Los Angeles
>
> Waypoints: Dallas, Bangor, Phoenix
>
> Destination: New York
>
> and the optimized output was ordered as follows:
>
> Origin: Los Angeles
>
> Waypoints: Phoenix, Dallas, Bangor
>
> Destination: New York
>
> then this field will be an Array containing the values [2, 0, 1]. Note that the numbering of waypoints is zero-based.
> If any of the input waypoints has **stopover** set to **false**, this field will be empty, since route optimization is not available for such queries.

Comment: Great, really appreciate it. I had looked through the documentation for waypoints (below),but didn't find what I was looking for. 
 :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints